# Need some simple clarification

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

I get so confused because I look at an equation like $F=ma$ and think, what are the chances that mass "multiplied" by acceleration equals force. What am I missing here?

Comment: The chances are 100%: mass times acceleration  equals force, always :)

Comment: This question is unclear; I’m confused about what your confusion is. What about an equality needs to be clarified?

Answer (score 1):

Newton observed the world and concluded that force is the product of mass and acceleration.  Many experiments have since provided supporting evidence.  Is it always true?  No, not always.  Newton's second law, $F = ma$, holds in general only in inertial (non-accelerating) frames and, at least in the form you have given, when objects are traveling at much less than the speed of light.  But as John Taylor says in his *Classical Mechanics*:

> In the classical domain, we can and shall assume that the first two
> laws (the second in either form [$F=ma$ is one form]) are universally and precisely valid.
> You can, if you wish, regard this assumption as defining a model — the
> classical model — of the natural world. The model is logically
> consistent and is such a good representation of many phenomena that it
> is amply worthy of our study.

After some years of study I don't struggle to understand $F=ma$ or Newton's other laws, but I still find it hard to imagine how Newton was inspired to discover them.  An extraordinary physicist.

Comment: Yes, he was an extraordinary genius. I rank him as the smartest (known) person in history. His laws of motion, gravitation and the construction of calculus, amongst other things, allow the world to run. How he accomplished this in his time, I also find *extremely* perplexing and almost unbelievable that one man could do so much in one lifetime. It’s extremely rare that people are born with such intelligence. Remarkable.